# How to write Java code for below curl command with content-type, Authorization, x-content-sha256 options

Tags: java, curl, https

I want to use Java only to execute this curl command. Currently, I am using shell script. I tried to search Java code but almost everyone is using shell script for this. Can someone please help me on this.

```bash
curl -k -v --data-binary @/tmp/payload.json -X POST -sS https://example.com/v2/search -H 'date: Thu, 02 Jun 2022 04:44:19 GMT' -H 'x-content-sha256: xgxgfdgdfgJ/fgdfg+cvbcvbcvbvcbcv=' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'content-length: 207' -H 'Authorization: Signature version="1",keyId="ocidx.tenancy.oc1..123455/ocidx.user.oc1..wergjkwerjkeg/12:df:fg:3b:0f:34:d1",algorithm="rsa-sha256",headers="(request-target) date host x-content-sha256 content-type content-length",signature="sadfkjagsdkfjgkjsdgfkjgsdakjfgkjsadgfjkdgsjkgsdjkgfkjsdfkhkj/sdkfjgsdkjgfjksdfkjggkjgsdf+sdfhjvsjhdh+t2n3EdHZO5Qg5fxTm8F/ZhZJmWdeB+S+6H9T84r0tZNB5s0+sdkfjhsdkjfhjkdsgfjkdsjkfdjkgkjsdgjkgdk/hV5t4wTK/alsdkhsalkhd+wrq3Uw=="'
```

Comment: _"almost everyone is using shell script for this"_ citation needed. I would guess that the majority of Java developers use something like Apache HttpClient, Spring RestTemplate, java.net.http.HttpClient, OkHttp or one of the other HTTP implementations in the Java ecosystem for this. However, as it stands, your question shows no effort, nor is it clear what part you're having problems with.

Comment: Your `'x-content-sha256: xgxgfdgdfgJ/fgdfg+cvbcvbcvbvcbcv=` is just a header.   That is what -H stands for.

Please look into https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html and how to pass headers.